# How to implement OpenAI self consistency prompting using python

Tags: python, openai-api, large-language-model

I am a kid in OpenAI, taking baby steps with few fumbles.  I am referring to https://www.promptingguide.ai to pick the concepts.  Since I am bit comfortable with Python I am trying it out the API calls using that.

One of the prompting technique explained is self consistency.  I have gone through the example provided, I couldnt figure out how to implement the same using Python.

Experts, can you please validate my understanding.  First we are providing example as in Few shots- chain of thoughts.  Then we will request to generate three (odd permutation) answers from the model.  We will compare the outputs and pick the most similar / matched answers.

If its wrong, kindly guide me.  I will add the playground snapshot link for the above discussed scenario here soon.

Thanks.
Subbu S.